# Will the width of water leaving the outlet section gradually decrease?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

[image: schematic diagram of a nozzle]

This is a schematic diagram of a nozzle. Its upper and lower surfaces are parallel, its vertical two sides are not parallel, and the width of the nozzle gradually decreases. Blue represents water ejected from the nozzle.

[image: top view of the nozzle]

This is the top view of the nozzle. Blue represents the water ejected from the nozzle.
My question is: will the width of water leaving the outlet section gradually decrease? Will the pressure of water leaving the outlet section be higher than atmospheric pressure? If we ignore the influence of gravity.
I think the answer is yes. Because it's like two streams of water colliding together. Two streams of water bounded by the axis of symmetry of the nozzle.

### People ignore inertia. It takes force for water to change the direction of velocity. Why does the water from the nozzle outlet section change its velocity direction?

[image: guess the distribution of axial pressure]

@ChetMiller

According to @ChetMiller's analysis, I guess the distribution of axial pressure is shown in the red curve in the figure.

Reference:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vena_contracta

Comment: @RalfB Is your answer yes?

Comment: @CherMiller  Is your answer yes?

Comment: For the geometry as you have drawn it with such a gradual taper, the effect will be negligible, and the pressure at the exit will differ negligibly from atmospheric.  Note also that nozzles are designed so that the angle of taper varies along the axis, and, approaching the exit, the nozzle taper is zero and the sides at the exit are parallel i.e, the cross sectional area becomes constant for a length before the exit).

Comment: @ChetMiller You ignore inertia. It takes force for water to change the direction of velocity. Why does the water from the nozzle outlet section change its velocity direction?

Comment: I didn't say it would have absolutely no effect.  I said that, for the taper as you have drawn, it would not have a *significant* effect on the exit pressure.  Plus, I also said that nozzles are not designed like you have drawn it.  They are designed so that the cross sectional area near the exit of the nozzle becomes constant.  So the direction of the velocity near the exit is parallel to the centerline.

Comment: @ChetMiller If the nozzle is designed according to my drawing, will there be the effect I said? Is the static pressure of the outlet section higher than atmospheric pressure?

Comment: You wish to look at cases in which the nozzle cross sectional area is still converging at the nozzle exit, and where there is a Vena Contracta to a little smaller final jet cross sectional area downstream of the nozzle exit?  You wish to determine the correction that would have to be applied to the total nozzle force to take this into account?  We can't predict the final jet cross sectional area without solving Euler's equation for incompressible inviscid flow, but, if we knew the final cross sectional area, we could determine the correction to the force.  Any interest?

Comment: @ChetMiller After the outlet section, the cross-sectional area of the fluid is smaller than the outlet cross-sectional area, which is a fact. Therefore, the pressure on the outlet section is certainly greater than atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Do you want to see the analysis or not?

Comment: @ChetMiller Please analyze it and let's see.

Comment: OK.  But, before I present the analysis, I want you to realize something.  The average pressure at the nozzle exit is not the only thing that changes in this Vena Contracta situation.  Because the axial and radial velocities of the fluid are functions of radial position at the nozzle exit (say, for a circular nozzle cross section), the axial momentum  of the fluid at the nozzle exit also changes.  So even if the average axial velocity over the exit cross section is $V_E$, the rate of momentum exiting the control volume is not simply $\rho V_E^2 A_E$.

Comment: This can affect our concussion with regard to the average pressure at the exit.

Comment: @ChetMiller Of course, we all know that it is complex near the exit section.

Answer (score 4):

The flow of most fluids through a hose, pipe, etc is not laminar (meaning you cannot assume all the water molecules are traveling in a straight line nearly parallel with  the edge of the nozzle).  Therefore, it is somewhat simplistic to think that the water flow will continue in a straight line path after it is emitted from the nozzle (neglecting gravity as you have suggested) causing the width of the water stream to continue to decrease after it has left the nozzle.

Further, the reason for tapering a nozzle is to increase the flow speed.  This is because an equal volume of water must pass through each section of the hose/nozzle over a fixed interval of time.  Therefore, as you decrease the width of the hose/nozzle you increase the velocity of the water.  Since there is no mechanism to increase the flow rate after the water has left the nozzle, it is unlikely that the width of the band of water will continue to get smaller after being ejected from the nozzle head.

Yes, the total pressure at the nozzle outlet will be greater than atmospheric pressure.  If it were not, the water would not be exiting the nozzle.  Note, that the total pressure is made up of two components:  a static pressure plus a dynamic pressure.  Generally you can think of the static pressure as being equal to the atmospheric pressure and the dynamic pressure as the additional pressure driving the flow of the water.

Comment: Is the pressure at the free surface of the stream atmospheric even slightly beyond the exit (neglecting surface tension)?  Is there a radial velocity in the jet?  If not, how can the pressure be anything but atmospheric throughout the jet (since, for an inviscid fluid, the stress tensor is isotropic and all components are equal to the pressure)?  On what basis do you say that if the total pressure at the nozzle outlet were not greater than atmospheric, the water could not be exiting the nozzle; Newton's first law says that a water stream in motion (with forward inertia) will continue in

Comment: motion on its own?

Comment: @ Chet Miller.  The static pressure is in balance with the atmospheric pressure, but the very motion of the water introduces an additional dynamic pressure.  Therefore, the total pressure (static + dynamic) must be greater than atmospheric pressure if water is being emitted from the nozzle head.

Comment: Ahh, the "total pressure."   I missed that.  I think you need to make it clear to this particular OP that "total pressure" is not what we normally think about when we discuss "the pressure."  When we are normally referring to "the pressure," what we mean is the static pressure.  What we are saying here is, at the exit of the nozzle, the pressure (aka static pressure) is equal to atmospheric pressure.  We don't want to leave him with the impression that the pressure at the nozzle exit is higher than atmospheric.

Comment: You ignore inertia. It takes force for water to change the direction of velocity. Why does the water from the nozzle outlet section change its velocity direction?

Comment: @JRL You ignore inertia. It takes force for water to change the direction of velocity. Why does the water from the nozzle outlet section change its velocity direction?

Comment: @ChetMiller I agree that in this case the water will be at atmospheric immediately after leaving the nozzle if it is flowing only axially. And I agree that if it is decreasing its radius for a bit just after leaving the nozzle that there will be only a negligible increase in pressure above atmospheric, unless/until it hits something. I also agree that ive been discussing static pressure just now and it is not normal to include kinetic head in “pressure”

Comment: @JRL see my reply to Chet if didnt get a notification

Answer (score 2):

We're going to be looking at a nozzle of circular cross section, that tapers in the axial direction such that its area is still decreasing at the nozzle exit and, as a result, a Vena Contracta forms by the exit jet.  Let the subscript U refer to the region upstream of the nozzle, E refer to the exit cross section, and $\infty$ refer to the final downstream region where the jet area becomes constant again.

Previously we had analyzed this system using a control volume that ran from upstream of the nozzle to the nozzle exit, but we assumed that, at the exit, the pressure is uniform at atmospheric pressure (gauge pressure of zero $p_E=0$) and flow streamlines that are parallel to the nozzle centerline, with a uniform exit velocity $V_E$.  For this approximation, we found that the axial force exerted by the nozzle on the fluid is in the opposite direction of the flow, and given by
$$F^*=\frac{\dot{M}^2A_U}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_E}-\frac{1}{A_U}\right]^2$$where $\dot{M}$ is the mass flow rate and $\rho$ is the fluid density, and where the superscript * on F indicates that it is the result of our approximation.  With this approximation, we also find that the upstream pressure is given by $$P_U^*=\frac{\dot{M}^2}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_E^2}-\frac{1}{A_U^2}\right]$$

If we re-analyze this problem by extending the control volume all the way to the final downstream area of the jet (beyond the Vena Contracta) where the pressure actually is atmospheric (and uniform), the axial velocity actually is uniform, and the streamlines are actually parallel to the nozzle axis, we find that the total axial force exerted by the nozzle and outside air (surrounding the exit jet) on the flowing fluid is now given by: $$F=\frac{\dot{M}^2A_U}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_{\infty}}-\frac{1}{A_U}\right]^2$$ And the upstream pressure is given by: $$P_U=\frac{\dot{M}^2}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_{\infty}^2}-\frac{1}{A_U^2}\right]$$Note that the force exerted by the outside air on the exit jet most be negligible (neglecting air drag), so F must be the corrected force exerted solely by the nozzle.  So the correction to the force as a result of relaxing the original assumptions and including the Vena Contracta effect must be $$\delta F=F-F^*=\frac{\dot{M}^2A_U}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_{\infty}}-\frac{1}{A_E}\right]\left[\frac{2}{A_U}+\frac{1}{A_{\infty}}+\frac{1}{A_E}\right]$$This equation indicates that, as a result of including convergence of the nozzle right up to the exit cross section, the calculated force of the nozzle on the flowing fluid is higher than when the effect is neglected.

Similarly, the correction to the upstream pressure is given by $$\delta P_U=P_U-P^*_U=\frac{\dot{M}^2}{2\rho}\left[\frac{1}{A_{\infty}^2}-\frac{1}{A_E^2}\right]$$  This equation indicates that, as a result of including convergence of the nozzle right up to the exit cross section, the calculated upstream pressure is higher than when the effect is neglected.

Next, let's focus on what's happening at the exit cross section.  Here, the exit pressure varies with radial position $P_E=P_E(r)$, the axial component of velocity varies with radial position $V_{zE}=V_{zE}(r)$, and there is a radial component of velocity that also varies with radial position $V_{rE}=V_{rE}(r)$. The average pressure and axial velocity (averaged over the exit cross section) are given by $$\bar{P}_E=\frac{\int_0^{R_E}{2\pi rP_E(r)dr}}{\pi R_E^2}$$and$$\bar{V}_{zE}=\frac{\int_0^{R_E}{2\pi r}V_{zE}(r)dr}{\pi R_E^2}=\frac{\dot{M}}{\rho A_E}$$where $R_E$ is the radius of the nozzle at the exit cross section.  In addition, we express the axial velocity at the exit as the average axial velocity plus the radially varying deviation of the axial velocity from the from the average:  $$V_{zE}=\frac{\dot{M}}{\rho A_E}+\delta V_{zE}(r)\tag{1}$$

Next, we perform a macroscopic momentum balance on the portion of the fluid jet within a control volume between the exit cross section and an arbitrary axial location beyond the Vena Contracta:  $$\bar{P_E}A_E=\rho V_{\infty}^2A_{\infty}-\rho \int_0^{R_E}{2\pi rV_{zE}^2(r)dr}$$If we substitute Eqn. 1 into this equation, we obtain:$$\bar{P_E}A_E=\rho V_{\infty}^2A_{\infty}-\frac{\dot{M}^2}{\rho A_E}-\rho \overline{(\delta V_{zE})^2}A_E\tag{2}$$where $$\overline{(\delta V_{zE})^2}=\frac{\int_0^{R_E}{2\pi r(\delta V_{zE}(r))^2dr}}{\pi R_E^2}$$The first term on the right hand side of Eqn.2 can be re-expressed as $$\rho V_{\infty}^2A_{\infty}=\frac{\dot{M}^2}{\rho A_{\infty}}$$Substituting this into Eqn.2 then yields for the average pressure at the nozzle exit $$\bar{P_E}=\frac{\dot{M}^2}{\rho A_E}\left[\frac{1}{A_{\infty}}-\frac{1}{A_E}\right]-\rho \overline{(\delta V_{zE})^2}$$The first term on the right hand side is clearly positive, but the second term is negative, and it is not clear which of these two terms will prevail.  Thus, according to this analysis, it is not obvious whether the average gauge pressure at the nozzle exit will be positive or negative.

Comment: You can analyze this problem purely, ignoring gravity, air drag, temperature change, friction, etc.

Comment: Isn't that what I've been doing?

Comment: I'm not continue on to analyzing the conditions at the exit cross section until you indicate that you are satisfied with what I have done so far.

Comment: Good analysis, please continue.

Comment: Analysis completed.

Comment: I voted this up awhile ago but just really read it now. Is good

Comment: @ChetMiller I added a graph at the end of the problem, which is my estimated axial pressure distribution. Of course, the axial pressure distribution inside the nozzle should also be considered for the distribution of outlet pressure. I think the acceleration inside the nozzle is not constant, so the pressure distribution along the axial direction is not so simple.

Comment: The cross-section average pressure variation you added assumes that the average pressure at the nozzle outlet is positive.  My analysis indicates that, depending on how the axial velocity varies with radial location at the outlet cross section, this may not be the case.  The gauge pressure within the nozzle could easily drop below zero approaching the exit, and then recover to zero with increasing axial position.  To resolve these issues, we would have to numerically solve Euler's equation both inside and outside the nozzle, including the effect of the free surface.

Comment: @ChetMiller Is there any way to measure the static pressure of the outlet section of the nozzle?

Comment: You must be careful.  There is not a single static pressure at the outlet.  The static pressure varies radially over the outlet cross section from a (probably) positive  value at the centerline to value of zero (gauge) at the surface.  I'm sure there is a way of measuring the static pressure distribution at the outlet, probably by orienting a stress transducer or manometer tube radially in the flow.  Then, the pressure distribution would have to be integrated over the area of the outlet flow to get the average static pressure over the cross section, or, equivalently, the "reaction force."

Answer (score 1):

> People ignore inertia. It takes force for water to change the direction of velocity. Why does the water from the nozzle outlet section change its velocity direction?

Very soon after leaving the nozzle the stream of water will break into drops. The more convergent or divergent the nozzle the smaller the drops. The force that drives the formation of drops is the surface tension.

Comment: Does it not become a water droplet at a distance from the nozzle section?